# need to create a mobile version to my navigation unsuccessfully

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have troubles with making an opening mobile version full width of my navigation bar. i tried making it every way possible unsuccessfully with out knowing what my problem is! 
i tried to use media but i have no idea what to do to make it looks like the hamburger style that come and goes. i have to mention that i use pure css so i lack of knowledge in JS.
if someone will to help me I will be greathful, because right now i stuck and i dont know what to so about that.

```
<nav class="navi" id="target">
<div class="menu">
    <a class="link-1" href="#">home</a>
    <a class="link-1" href="#">info</a>
    <a class="link-1" href="#">contact</a>
    <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img alt="Brand" src="logo2.png" height="40px" width="60px"></a>
    </div>
</div>

</nav>
```

this is the css for the navigation:

```
width:100%;
margin-top: 0;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position:fixed;

text-align:right;
z-index:10;


}
.navi{
background: rgba(0,0, 0, 0.5);


}
.navi:hover{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 1);
}

.link-1 {
transition: 0.3s ease;
color: #fff;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
border-top: 1px solid ;
text-align:right;
padding: 20px 0px;
margin: 0 20px;
font-weight: italic;
letter-spacing:2px;
}
.link-1:hover {
border-top: 2px solid #fff;

text-decoration: none;
color:#fff;

padding: 3px 6px;

}


.logo{
text-align:left;
margin-left:35px;
margin-top:-25px;
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for asking specific programming questions, you shouldn't simply ask users to edit your code for you. Isolate the problem and ask a specific question about it to learn for yourself. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Listen to Dan. Definitely recommend reading the link he posted above. I had to learn this lesson the hard way when I started posting here.

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/ 1st thing on google... here you go...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Bootstrap 3. Go to getbootstrap.com Make sure to include bootstrap's css and javascript pages into your project. The code for your hamburger style nav bar should look something like this:

```
<div class="container" id="main">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills unstyled">
            <li class=""><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
             <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#footer">Contact </a></li>
        </ul>


<!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Note: You will only see the hamburger style if you resize your browser window below the breakpoint.